# Avoiding identifying objects within previously identified objects in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Apologies if the question title is confusing.

I've got some code below in MATLAB, which identifies squares/rectangles in an image.

```
img = imread('image.jpg');
imgbw = im2bw(image);
filter = bwareafilt(imagebw, [800 10000]);
fill = imfill(imgbw,'holes');
area = bwareaopen(fill,15);
final = bwlabel(area);
dets = regionprops(final,'boundingbox');
figure(1), imagesc(I1); hold on;
for count = 1 : numel(dets)
    gg = dets(count).BoundingBox;
    rectangle('position',gg,'edgecolor','r','linewidth',2);
end
```

I keep getting results where I am identifying squares, within another square I have already identified. i.e.:

[image]

What I wanted, was to identify the yellow as one square/rectangle, and leave it at that.  But as you can see, I've identified my rectangle/square, but also identified squares in the middle.  Does anyone know how I can get ignore shapes, that are also inside previously identified squares?

Comment: once you get a meaningful shape, say the outer one(yellow), you capture those pixel boundaries and dont go into those boundaries. Hope this hint helps!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives to this.

1. Adjust your opening parameter so that you end up with a fully connected shape. Say, instead of 15 you can use 25.
2. You can find the areas of all intersecting polygons using e.g. [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18173-polygon-intersection). If the area of an intersection is higher than a given threshold, discard the polygon.

After finding overlapping polygons, you could consider averaging the hypothesis so that you end up with a more correct shape pose.